# Prevent word-break: initial from wrapping hyphens?

Tags: css

I need a sentence to break when it's containing element gets smaller but for words to not break. The CSS rule of `word-break: initial;` does this except the `-` character does break:

```
<div class="cont">
  <div class="text">Here is some text-wrapping</div>
</div>
<div class="cont">
  <div class="text">Here is some text1wrapping</div>
</div>

.cont {
  background: grey;
  max-width: 70px;
  overflow: auto;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.text {
  word-break: initial;
}
```

https://codepen.io/adsfdsfhdsafkhdsafjkdhafskjds/pen/GRmvMrY

[image]

Is there a way to stop `-` from being wrappable?

Answer (score 0):

You can put that into a `span` and apply `white-space: nowrap;` to it:

```css
.cont {
  background: grey;
  max-width: 70px;
  overflow: auto;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.text {
  word-break: initial;
}
.no {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="cont">
  <div class="text">Here is some text-wrapping</div>
</div>
<div class="cont">
  <div class="text">Here is some <span class="no">text-wrapping</span></div>
</div>
```